# Uncaught TypeError: child.transform is undefined PIXI.particles.ParticleContainer with vue2-leaflet and leaflet-pixi-overlay

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, pixi.js

I'm trying to follow the example [many-markers](https://manubb.github.io/Leaflet.PixiOverlay/many-markers.html) using Vue2-Leaflet and Leaflet-Pixi-Overlay. However, when I add the Container Particle it is displaying the error as shown in the image below, on line 153 of the link below.  Could anyone help? I thank.

```
var innerContainer = new PIXI.particles.ParticleContainer(markersLength, {vertices: true,});
for (var i = 0; i < markersLength; i++) {
    var coords = project([getRandom(48.7, 49), getRandom(2.2, 2.8)]);
    innerContainer.addChild({ 
       x: coords.x - origin.x,
       y: coords.y - origin.y,
     });
}
```

https://gist.github.com/lordjack/74571373f6c59288f5af8f6736e0a77c

[image]